# Query for a view to get list of dates in a date range and divide amount

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following fields:

| LineId | FromDate | ToDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 10.01.2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 05.07.2021 | 07.07.2021 | 300 |

and so on, I have 91M rows

I want a query which will help me create a view with following data:

| Lineid | FromDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 02.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 03.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 04.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 05.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 06.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 07.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 08.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 09.01.2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 10.01.2021 | 10 |
| 2 | 05.07.2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 06.07.2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 07.07.2021 | 100 |

I cant write a stored procedure. It has to be done using a view only.

Appreciate your help in this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JOIN your table to a Calendar table

Comment: FYI, they aren't "record lines", they are rows.

Comment: thanks, i am correcting it

Comment: What if you had an amount like 33 to be applied over 10 days - what would the daily amount be? Or amount of 10 over 3 days?

Comment: 33/10 = 3.3 The amount just needs to be split into the number of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you need a tally table (AKA *numbers table*.)

```
;--==== Tally Table
DECLARE @Rows INT = 10;

WITH E1(N)     AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)),
     iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 AS b)
SELECT t.N
FROM iTally AS t
WHERE t.N <= @Rows;
```

This gets you as many rows as you need (up to 100 for this example.)

```
N
------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Next, lets determine the correct amounts and number of rows required:

```
;--==== 1. Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (
  LineId   INT,
  FromDate DATE,
  ToDate   DATE,
  Amount   INT);

INSERT @t VALUES
(1, '01.01.2021', '10.01.2021', 100),
(2, '05.07.2021', '07.07.2021', 300);

;--==== 2. Calculate # of months and divide amount by months for "Amount"
SELECT
  LineID = t.LineId,
  Months = mo.Months,
  Amount = t.Amount/mo.Months
FROM   @t AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEDIFF(MONTH,t.FromDate,t.ToDate)+1)) AS mo(Months)
```

This returns:

```
LineID      Months      Amount
----------- ----------- -----------
1           10          10
2           3           100
```

Now we will use the number of months to determine how many rows to generate:

```
;--==== 3. Solution
WITH E1(N)     AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)),
     iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 AS b)
SELECT 
  LineId   = t.LineId,
  FromDate = DATEADD(MONTH,tally.N-1,t.FromDate),
  Amount   = t.Amount/mo.Months
FROM        @t                                              AS t
CROSS APPLY iTally                                          AS tally
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEDIFF(MONTH,t.FromDate,t.ToDate)+1)) AS mo(Months)
WHERE       tally.N <= mo.Months
ORDER BY    t.LineId -- Not required;
```

**Results:**

```
LineId      FromDate   Amount
----------- ---------- -----------
1           2021-01-01 10
1           2021-02-01 10
1           2021-04-01 10
1           2021-05-01 10
1           2021-06-01 10
1           2021-07-01 10
1           2021-08-01 10
1           2021-09-01 10
1           2021-10-01 10
1           2021-03-01 10
2           2021-07-07 100
2           2021-06-07 100
2           2021-05-07 100
```

As a view you would replace my sample temp table with the real one.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YOUR_VIEW AS
WITH E1(N)     AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)),
     iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1, E1 AS b)
SELECT 
  LineId   = t.LineId,
  FromDate = DATEADD(MONTH,tally.N-1,t.FromDate),
  Amount   = t.Amount/mo.Months
FROM        @t                                              AS t
CROSS APPLY iTally                                          AS tally
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEDIFF(MONTH,t.FromDate,t.ToDate)+1)) AS mo(Months)
WHERE       tally.N <= mo.Months
ORDER BY    t.LineId -- Not required;
```